# Responsive div with background-image and content

Tags: css

Im trying to get a div to display a background-image with the same aspect-ratio as it would do if I had an img element and used boostrap `img-fluid` class. I tried using percentage for padding the content, but it does not work that great. Is there any better way to calculate so the height and width is correct in all screensizes?

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hayz94gL/) with my problem. The first image is on a background-image, and the second one is there as an reference to what the image should look like in every size.

```css
.img-container{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/390");
}

.img-container .panel{padding: 14% 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid img-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      Logo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel text-xs-center">
        <h1>Heading goes here</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/390" class="img-fluid" alt="Reference image size">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try to use `background-size: contain` in stead of `cover`

Comment: `background-size: contain` may be better, but the padding calculation still is not effective using percentage. Using contain, I get white borders on top and bottom of the background-image.

Comment: Why are you using `padding` actually? You want to center the text?

Comment: Yes, the `.panel` should be at the center of the div, both vertical and horizontal. Padding seem to work, but Im asking for help, since it does not fix it completely.